# How to get all constraint type in mysql?

Tags: mysql, constraints

I want to store tables metadata into other table.So how to get all constraint and its type like whether it primary , unique or foreign key.

table_name                      constraint_name                     constraint_type

user                            pk_user_id                           PRIMARY_KEY

user_role                       fk_role                             FOREIGN_KEY

user                          unique_email                         UNIQUE_KEY

Answer (score 1):

For that You can use  `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;`

And also try this way

```
select * from information_schema.table_constraints where constraint_schema = 'YOUR_DB'
```

For more information visit this [Table Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/table-constraints-table.html)

Also try this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT(constraint_name) FROM information_schema.table_constraints  WHERE constraint_schema = 'YOUR_DB' ORDER BY constraint_name ASC;
```